# python opencv: no image

Tags: python, opencv, camera, capture

I am trying to capture from a Sony Handicam DCR-HC38, running the code below, and passing [-1 .. 3] to the CaptureFromCAM function.  The code runs, but I get no image.  Do I need to "wrap" the camera somehow?  Skype recognizes the camera, but python/opencv won't.  I'm running Windows Vista if that helps any.

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow("camera", 1)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)

while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage("camera", img)
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break
```

Comment: img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
needs to be tested for if img actually has a value or is None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try increasing the delay on the cv.WaitKey

Answer (score 3):

not sure if you fixed it or not. But the solution I figured out is by checking which driver OpenCv is trying to access... I have both v4l1 and v4l2, however I can only access device /dev/video0 by using gstreamer codec and the v4l2 driver on my lenovo x200 (internal webcam) using ubuntu 10.10. So I had to recompile Opencv from source, by firstly applying the patch found at:

[Opencv-2.0.0.link.v4l2.patch](http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/mandriva/devel/cooker/SRPMS/main/release/opencv-2.2.0-4.src.html)

extract the patch to your opencv root directory: then open terminal and cd to the opencv root directory, and do the following:

```
patch -p0 <OpenCV-2.0.0-link-v4l2.patch
```

then:

```
make
make install
```

Now your opencv libraries should access the v4l2 driver instead, hope this helps someone